# JSP doesn't accept <% %> scriptlet syntax

Tags: java, jsp

I am currently running a simple Java web app. I need to write Java code inside some jsp files.

When inserting Java code I can use  tag but if I try to use <% ... %> (<%@ ... %>, <%! ... %>, <%= ... %> and so on) it will give me exception like:
"The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup"

I need to first declare a method, and then assign to jsp variable with the return value of the method. With  tag, I didn't find it working.

The container is **Tomcat 7** in response to helpers' question.

Comment: Hi, can you try a simplified jsp page: <html>Hi <%= 1+1 %></html>   and tell what you see on your browser ? Also what container are you using, e.g. tomcat?

Comment: Your servlet container (Tomcat? JBoss? ...?) expects the JSP to be in X(HT)ML format, i.e. using `<jsp:scriptlet>...</jsp:scriptlet>` instead of `<% ... %>`, `<jsp:expression>...</jsp:expression>` instead of `<%= ... %>` etc., see [JSP Syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm). This can be caused by the servlet container's configuration, or by how your page is declared, see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajq.html

Comment: The container is Tomcat 7. I have also put that on the question.